# How to add class_weight to a custom train_step function in a custom keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow 2.8. I followed a [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit#supporting_sample_weight_class_weight) from tensorflow on how to create your own fit function by overwriting the `train_step` function in your custom keras model class.

I wanted to add `class_weight` but in their section "Supporting sample_weight & class_weight" they don't show how to actually use `class_weight`, only `sample_weight`.

Is there a way to use `class_weight` in a custom `train_step` function?

I also found this Colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/nikitamaia/e4c0779d0d8d885b76933240986ea697/class_weight_mnist.ipynb#scrollTo=lQrqTbabO51q) in a GitHub issue. However this creates a custom model class but doesn't even use it and is therefore of no help either.

When actually creating the custom model and calling `fit()` I get the error: `TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_weight'`, when the loss in `train_step()` is calculated.

Example code (with the error) of what I'm trying to do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
# Prepare the training dataset.
batch_size = 64
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, 784))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (-1, 784))

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation.
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

# Prepare the training dataset.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(batch_size)

# Get model
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, name="predictions")(x)

# Instantiate an optimizer to train the model.
optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)
# Instantiate a loss function.
loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

# Prepare the metrics.
train_acc_metric = keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
        # on what you pass to `fit()`.
        if len(data) == 3:
            x, y, class_weight = data
        else:
            x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute the loss value.
            # The loss function is configured in `compile()`.
            loss = self.compiled_loss(
                y,
                logits,
                class_weight=class_weight,
                regularization_losses=self.losses,
            )

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update the metrics.
        # Metrics are configured in `compile()`.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, class_weight=class_weight)

        # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value.
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}


# Construct and compile an instance of CustomModel
model = CustomModel(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss_fn, metrics=["accuracy"])

class_weight = {
    0: 1.0,
    1: 1.0,
    2: 1.0,
    3: 1.0,
    4: 1.0,
    # Set weight "2" for class "5",
    # making this class 2x more important
    5: 2.0,
    6: 1.0,
    7: 1.0,
    8: 1.0,
    9: 1.0,
}

model.fit(train_dataset, class_weight=class_weight, epochs=3)
```

All those examples do not work because loss functions don't take `class_weight` as an argument, as far as I understand when looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy).

I tried to fix this by creating my own loss function:

```
@tf.function
def weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, class_weight=None):
    loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(labels, logits)
    if class_weight is None:
        if debug:
            print("None weights: NO WEIGHTS SET!")
        return loss

    # get all class weights as list
    if type(class_weight) is not list:
        class_weight = list(class_weight.values())

    class_weights_gathered = tf.gather(class_weight, labels)

    return tf.reduce_mean(class_weights_gathered * loss)
```

Then using this to compile my model and calling `.fit()`

```
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=weighted_sparse_categorical_crossentropy)
model.fit(X, class_weight=class_weight, epochs=1)
```

But I still get `TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'class_weight'` despite `class_weight` being clearly an argument in my function.

I also looked at [GitHub](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1404) to see what Tensorflow actually does with the `class_weight` inside the `.fit()` function and seems to convert it to a `sample_weight` somehow.

So I'm not sure if what I want is even possible. But then the section in the official [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit#supporting_sample_weight_class_weight) would be wrong since there would be no support for `class_weight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the error is here:

```
loss = self.compiled_loss(
    y,
    logits,
    class_weight=class_weight,
    regularization_losses=self.losses,
)
```

because `class_weight` is not recognized... instead, you should use `sample_weight`, and from [keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/#supporting-sampleweight-amp-classweight) seems that is as simple as expanding the incoming data, as you are doing:

```
def train_step(self, data):
   x, y, sample_weight = data
```

your doubt about the "missing example", is due to the fact that keras will automatically transform your `class_weight` to `sample_weight`, as you can see from there code:

```
class M(K.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        tf.print(data)
        return {"loss":0}

model = M()
model.compile(K.optimizers.Adam(), K.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(np.array([[-1], [-1], [-1]]), np.array([[0],[0],[1]]), class_weight={0:7, 1:9})
```

which prints:

```
([[-1][-1][-1]], 
 [[0] [1] [0]], 
 [7 9 7])
```

where you can clearly see that the first line are the `x`, the second line are the `y`, the third one are the associated class weights to `y`, which you can feed to a loss as usual:

```
x, y, sample_weight = data
... 
loss = self.compiled_loss(
    y,
    logits,
    sample_weight=sample_weight,
    regularization_losses=self.losses,
)
```

Comment: Ye ok you are right i simply wasnt aware that class_weight gets converted to sample_weight based on the batch size when reading it from the data object within train_step(). Thanks